# How to check if a raster in PostgreSQL table is tiled

Tags: postgis, postgresql, st-intersects

I have inherited a PostgreSQL db and  I am trying to run queries like this:

```
UPDATE geomtable a 
    SET column = ST_Value(b.rast, 1, a.geom)
    FROM rastertable b
    WHERE  ST_Intersects(b.rast,a.geom);
```

It is very slow which makes me think the rasters, which are big (6000x4000), are not tiled. How can I check if they are tiled and if so what size the tiles are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://postgis.net/docs/using_raster_dataman.html):

The `blocksize_x` and `blocksize_y` columns in the `raster_columns` view represent the width and height (in pixels) of the raster blocks (often called tiles) in the raster column.

```
SELECT 
    r_table_name, 
    r_raster_column, 
    blocksize_x, 
    blocksize_y
FROM 
    raster_columns 
WHERE 
    r_table_name = 'mytable' 
    AND r_raster_column = 'rast';
```

So if the raster is stored as one large block (meaning it's not split into smaller tiles), then the `blocksize_x` and `blocksize_y` values would match the overall width and height of the raster. On the other hand, if the raster is stored as multiple tiles (split into smaller blocks), the `blocksize_x` and `blocksize_y` values would be smaller than the overall width and height of the raster.

Comment: Thank you.  raster_columns contained all the info I needed. Blocksizes are all null.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Goomer feel free to accept the answer (click on the checkmark) if you believe it is the best solution to your problem